# Getting error "No keyword with name 'Start' found." while running sikuliLibrary with robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework, sikuli

I have written following code and checked in side-packages folder SikuliLibaray is available.

```
*** Settings ***   
Library  SikuliLibrary  mode=NEW   
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
TC_001 Start Broser on window
      Start  Sikuli  Process
      Add Image Path  C:/python/SikuliImage
      Click  FileManager.png
```

But it is failing by showing the error:

`No keyword with name 'Start' found.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you have 2 spaces between each two words in the keyword `Start Sikuli Process`. Or at least that's how you formatted the code in your question.

If that's true, you need to get rid of one space, RF should process `Start Sikuli Process` as one keyword, but can't if you separate each two words by more than one space.

How to separate keywords is mentioned [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#space-separated-format) in the documentation, you might want to read it.